# Why is this private static property shown as unused by sonarlint?

Tags: phpstorm, sonarlint

Sonarlint seems to think that a private static property that is accessed within the class (by classname, not by `self`) is unused. I'm not really sure why this is: It might be that it is considered a bug in the code to access the current class by name rather then by `self` or even `static`, but I would expect that to be the error as this implies you can safely remove the property, which is not the case. It can of course be a bug (false positive) in sonarlint

I've written this example:

```
class TestClass
{
    private static $used = 'foobar';

    public static function echoUsed()
    {
        echo TestClass::$used;
    }

}

TestClass::echoUsed();
```

This runs fine, but it does produce the 'php s1068' warning below. I've added a picture of the popup and the complete error.

Does anybody know if this is on purpose as described above, or a bug?

---

The errors:

[image: example of the warning in phpstorm]

The 'more' link shows the complete error:

---

If a `private` field is declared but not used in the program, it can be considered dead code and should therefore be removed. This will
improve maintainability because developers will not wonder what the variable is used for.

### Noncompliant Code Example

```
class MyClass {
  private $foo = 4;                       //foo is unused

  public function compute($a) {
    return $a * 4;
  }
}
```

### Compliant Solution

```
class MyClass {

  public function compute($a) {
    return $a * 4;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's either a bug .. or you may bee seeing a response for a cached version (before you put the code that actually uses that property. Try `Code | Run Inspection By Name...` on that file (on even `Inspect Code`) -- see if that will make any difference. See if restarting IDE helps as well. No better suggestion from me (not using that plugin myself so no personal experience with possible bugs/behaviour).

Comment: It's not a caching issue; it does work (and change back/forth) if I change it between this and `self` or `static`